# How to get List consisted by repeated items in Perl6?

Tags: list, raku, repeat, timtowtdi

I try to use: `(^10).map({0})` to generate a list with 10 '0'.
Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Note in this case you don't need parens `()`, just a well placed space (after the `^10`) and a colon `:`. `^10 .map:{0}`. It may still be advisable to leave the parens around `^10` though.

Comment: @BradGilbert Isn't that a change from how it used to be? If so, do you recall roughly when that happened? I'm surprised but tentatively pleased to see it. I've always hoped we could make stuff like `-1 ** 2` DWIM. My hopes are up given the change I think I'm seeing (or, even if it's always been the same, it seems to be that the precedence of a method call with a space is lower than the `^` prefix but the error message of `^10.foo` says a method call without the space has higher precedence). Fwiw, for a moment I thought you meant `^10 .map({0})` wouldn't work. (Now I see what you meant.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
0 xx 10
```

Generates a list of 10 integers numbered zero.

```
'0' xx 10
```

Generates a list of 10 strings consisting of the single character '0'.

See [`xx` infix op doc](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/xx).

```
'0' x 10
```

Generates a single string consisting of a sequence of 10 '0' characters.

See [`x` infix op doc](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/x).

Comment: Perhaps also good to know: if you want a infinite list of `0`s, simply say that: `0 xx Inf`, or even shorter using the `Whatever`: `0 xx *`